# My JSON decoder is not working and I'm not sure why

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I'm trying to access a nested JSON variable called 'block' but I cannot seem to access it in any of the ways I've tried. Here's an example JSON message and my code:

> {"account":"xrb_34tsctqcgctm8fhnpat351z4f64rgz8o9y7gwh1dutjf1r7iiwfzruawhatz","hash":"E5935C559748444D09E97D6D13FDB48B51F46A01FA9F6FB2DBD3576D684A53C6","block":"{\n    \"type\": \"state\",\n    \"account\": \"xrb_34tsctqcgctm8fhnpat351z4f64rgz8o9y7gwh1dutjf1r7iiwfzruawhatz\",\n    \"previous\": \"78446816869EEEF4BC735B1A21AB33ED246A10303B87F0CAFD7CCD56406E0456\",\n    \"representative\": \"xrb_3pczxuorp48td8645bs3m6c3xotxd3idskrenmi65rbrga5zmkemzhwkaznh\",\n    \"balance\": \"320000000000000000000000000\",\n    \"link\": \"8DE4EE799910E26C5E44CDD345B8C8070E1955284BC407660825B425FBEDBB6B\",\n    \"link_as_account\": \"xrb_35h6xswsk694fjh6bmgmapwei3rg57ckiky61xm1ibfn6qxyugud9eo1fauk\",\n    \"signature\": \"E4AF5BBDF583509DF3147004AB61FEC04F9007AC23A46A2E2E5BE4B65D0788F45F89EEC7B62D0F42144A9F5EA090EF3F58262070F07C59F1AD752B5CC3BF9D04\",\n    \"work\": \"a56cb9e8d2539f73\"\n}\n","amount":"1`

```
struct IncomingBlock: Decodable {
    var account: String
    var hash: String

    struct Block: Decodable {
        var type: String
        var previous: String
        var link: String
        var link_as_account: String
        var representative: String
        var account: String
        var balance: String
        var work: String
        var signature: String
    }

    var block: Block
}

// in another file
guard let data = msg.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
guard let incomingBlock = try?JSONDecoder().decode(IncomingBlock.self, from: data) else { return }
```

Comment: Show your attempt to access the data. But first, change `try?` to `try` inside a `do/catch` where you do `print(error)` inside the `catch`. Then you will know any error instead of ignoring it.

Comment: Your `block` content seems to be double encoded, which is often found in an API designed by poor server side engineers. Tell the server side engineer to make the API to return a non-double-encoded JSON. Or you may need to decode it as String and re-decode it as JSON.

Comment: you can write a custom init decoder to deal with it for now or better change your response

Comment: @rmaddy so I have a try but I do not see an error```do{
            let iincomingBlock = try JSONDecoder().decode(IncomingBlock.self, from: data)
                print(iincomingBlock)
                
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("failure\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }```

Comment: If there is no error then what is the question? And just print `error`, not `error.localizedDescription`. You'll see more detail.

Comment: @OOPer I attempted but I couldn't convert back to json since I could only cast to `Any` or `AnyObject`

Comment: What have you attempted? Telling something to the server side engineer? I have proposed to re-decode, nothing like _cast to `Any` or `AnyObject`_.

Comment: @OOPer I haven't, but they are trying to do a major update currently. You were right, I did a recode and I'm getting the field I wanted, thanks

Comment: @rmaddy solved the issue with a re-decode that OOPer suggested, I'm not sure what the error was earlier. Thanks for your help in making me think about errors more

Comment: Thanks for reporting. If you can post an answer, it may help some developers suffering with the ill-designed APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially to access the nested `JSON` variable `block` I had to decode the initial `JSON` message

```
do{
  guard let data = inital_msg.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
  let incomingBlock = try JSONDecoder().decode(IncomingBlock.self, from: data) 
catch ...{}
```

and have the `block`'s value cast to String in the model.

```
struct IncomingBlock: Decodable {
var account: String
var hash: String
var block: String
}
```

After that, I then decoded the initial messages `block` field once more like so

// Second JSON

```
let json = incomingBlock.block.data(using: .utf8)!
```

finally with the separated block model:

```
 struct BlockMeta: Decodable {
    var type: String
    var previous: String
    var link: String
    var link_as_account: String
    var representative: String
    var account: String
    var balance: String
    var work: String
    var signature: String
 }
```

I could access the fields

```
 let block = try JSONDecoder().decode(BlockMeta.self, from: json)
 block.balance //returns "320000000000000000000000000"
```